# pug добавляет пустую строку (pre-line)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, pug

Как можно избежать пустой строки в `pug`, когда я задаю свойство `white-space: pre-line;` ?

**pug:**

```
#root 
  |Hello world
  |Hello world
```

**css:**

```
div {
  font-size:20px;
  color:red;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

#root {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

**P.S:** Без использования тега `br`!

Comment: `#root 
  |Hello world
  br
  |Hello world` а если так? и без `white-space: pre-line;`

Comment: Нужно использование без br. Т.е хочется полностью повторить поведение чистого html. https://codepen.io/vinetsky/pen/yGzqPM

Answer (score 2):

Волшебным образом оно срабатывает , если переписать конструкцию на mixin

```
mixin truncate(...items)
+e('blockquote').blockquote
    each item in items
       | !{item}

+truncate('hello world', 'world hello')
```